Calculate the offset needed to invert / collapse faces to center of a dodecahedron using geometry nodes
Calculate the offset needed to invert / collapse faces to center of a dodecahedron.
I want to calculate the required offsets to have an object's "inverted" faces collapse to the center of an object. See animated gif below.

Link to animated gif



Example:  The radius of an object is set to 2mm, but when I manually "invert" faces, my offset needs to be around -1.260.  How can I calculate this / What is the formula needed to do this when I need the radius to be 4.93mm, 2.34mm, etc..

Blend File:


Actually the answer by @vklidu is better/simpler than mine. For controlling the offset towards the center you could directly connect the Offset Scale of the Extrude Mesh with the Group Input (see also my comment under his solution).

Probably Vector Math > Scale -1 will work that way... ?

When used in your case ...



Oh, of course. I was too much thinking about leaving possibilities to tweak things individually if you do not want to simply scale towards the center - which is why I also used distance instead of length in the first place. Although I was wrong, then a Subtract node would have been better in this case to define a different location to move the points to. So actually your solution is better, the Offset Scale could then be connected to the Group Input node.

Have I missed something? Distance to origin needs to be 1?

@RobinBetts ... if your comment goes to me - sorry, I didnt catch the point.

Hi. @vklidu ... my  comment made before 2nd illustration .. so now wrong :) offset by Position * -1 .. fine.  so will delete.

-1 is also in originál version, but if you think it is solved for you, probably better to leave it fór me :)

When you want to be able to change the radius dynamically, why do you want to set the Offset Scale manually? With the radius of 2 mm it would have been -1.262955 actually not -1.260 for example, the formula is simply height of the dodecahedron divided by 2. And for the height at a given radius there are certainly formulas to find somewhere which I'm not looking up now.
But: instead take the Position of each point and calculate its Distance from the center with a Vector Math node, I used distance here between the position and (0, 0, 0), but in this case you could have simply set the Vector Math node to Length which gives the same result.
Then Multiply by -1 with a Math node and plug it into the Offset Scale to move the points to the center.
Now the only thing that's left is controlling it with the Offset Scale value from the Group Input. So between multiplying by -1 and the Offset Scale of the Extrude Mesh node you put another Math node set to Multiply, to multiply the distance with the Group Input value. This way you can use it as a percentage rather than having absolute values. 0 is not moving inwards at all, 0.5 is 50% towards the center, 1 is 100% in the center, no matter which radius you have set. To move vertices outwards use negative values.



If you Capture Attribute remember which vertices are the 'pokes' in your pentagonal faces, you can selectively scale them .. 1 for flat faces, 0 for all at center.


I don't think I understood what Capture Attribute node does here, isnt it what just "Top" output socket achieved?

@vklidu you're probably absolutely right.. I think I'd assumed 'Top' would not survive 'Merge' .. If you haven't checked, I will. Maybe this answer should go. It's pretty much the same as yours, revised.
